# Practical use of metaprogramming

Tags: metaprogramming

I started to learn metaprogramming. So far I used it to read annotations in Java and create sql statements based on given class but I don't see any practical use in it. Can you give me an example where and how you used it in your programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotating a method to be recogonized as a unit test.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import example.util.Calculator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MyFirstJUnitJupiterTests {

    private final Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    @Test
    void addition() {
        assertEquals(2, calculator.add(1, 1));
    }
}
```

Note that the annotation here `@Test` exists as a flag.  When the test runner launches, it registers a listener for annotated methods, and if it encounters an annotated method that is annotated with the `Test` annotation interface, it will register that test in the "list of tests to run"

See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/ for more details.

There are many examples of annotations in the wild.  This is just but one of them.